# javascript createElement with property

Tags: javascript, properties, createelement

I'm trying to add a element from Javascript with classname person.

It works perfectly fine by below code.

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.classList.add('person');
```

But why the below not working?

```
const element = document.createElement('div').classList.add('person');
```

Comment: This is due to the order in which the operations are performed.
In the first code, you are creating createElement('div') and then adding the class person.

In the other code, you are trying to perform both operations at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.createElement()` returns an element, but calling `.classList.add` on an element doesn't return that same element.

In your first code, `element` becomes a newly created element. Then on the next line, you call its `.classList.add()` method to add a class to that element. The `element` variable itself was never changed, but `.classList.add()` changed some internal property of `element`.

In your second code, you create a new element with `document.createElement()`, then immediately call `.classList.add()` to add a class to that element. Then `.classList.add()` doesn't return anything, so the `element` variable has the value `undefined`. Variables are only assigned the last value returned by a function when chaining functions together.

If you really wanted to make the last one work, then you'd need to create a new function that calls `.classList.add()` then returns the element, like this:

```js
function addClass(el, className) {
  el.classList.add(className);
  return el;
}

const element = addClass(document.createElement('div'), 'person');
console.log(element);
```

Comment: @nasirMasud Always happy to help! You can mark my answer as correct (the checkmark) to indicate that my answer solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet:

```
document.createElement('div').classList.add('person')
```

is not considered valid because the `classList.add()` method does not return the current element with the added class. Instead, it returns undefined.

The correct approach is to first create the object using `document.createElement('div')`, and then add the class to the element.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I'm aware of to write this functionality is:

```js
// a named Arrow function, that takes two arguments:
// elementType: String, the type of element you wish to create ('div', 'span', 'p'...), and
// properties: Object detailing the properties, and their values, you wish to assign to
//             the created element, eg {...className: 'person', textContent: 'This is text'...}
// Object.assign() takes multiple Objects and copies the enumerable properties of one or more
// Objects and to the first Object (the 'target'), here this takes the properties from
// the properties Object, and copies them into the created element:
const create = (elementType, properties) => Object.assign(
  document.createElement(elementType),
  properties
);

// here we retrieve the <body> element, and then
document.querySelector('body')
  // call Element.append() to append the created-element (from
  // the create() function) to the document:
  .append(create('div', {classList: 'person'}));
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.person {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
}

.person::before {
  content: 'This is an element with the class of "person."';
}

div {
  outline: 4px solid #f90;
}
```

As for the actual question:

> But why [is] the below not working?

```
const element = document.createElement('div').classList.add('person');
```

That's due to final use of the `classList` API, as the `classList.add()` method as it returns only `undefined`:

```js
let element = document.createElement('div');

console.log(element.classList.add('person'));

document.querySelector('body').append(element);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.person {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
}

.person::before {
  content: 'This is an element with the class of "person."';
}

div {
  outline: 4px solid #f90;
}
```

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).